# salesforce chatter error

Tags: chatter

While I am trying to access my chatter desktop application, I am facing the error "Chatter is not enabled for this organization".

I have just changed my password. Any help would be appreciated.

I am still facing the issue even after I have enabled the option which you suggested

Comment: Chatter Desktop app was retired in May 2018 and no longer works.  https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000267581&type=1

Answer (score 0):

To enable Chatter at your organization, from Setup menu--> Chatter Settings and choose `Enable`

[image: Chatter Settings]

Comment: its been enabled

Comment: Are you still facing issues? If so then edit your question